# Bootstrap 2 Modals on 1 Page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make 2 modals on one page, one for a sign in form, the other for a signup form. Below are the declarations

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signUpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal fade" id="signInModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
```

And here are the links that show the modals:

```
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signUpModal">Sign Up</a>
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#signInModal">Sign In</a>
```

When I click the link to #signUpModal it works fine, however when I click the link to #signInModal, nothing happens, no modal is shown. If i then click the link to #signUpModal, the #signInModal then shows stacked on top of the #signUpModal.

How do I get the 2nd modal to appear correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Use code as below:

**NOTE!**

put attention that you don't set same `id` twice... `id` is uniqe and you can use it once in each page(for eample:`id="exampleModalLabel"` so in second model set `id="exampleModalLabel2"`)

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalIn">
  Sing in
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalIn" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sing in</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalOut">
  Sign out
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalOut" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel2">Sign out</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `href="#idOfModal"` when using with a , use `data-target="#idOfModal"` when using button

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#signupModal">Sign Up</a>
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="modal" href="#signinModal">Sign In</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="signinModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signinModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign In</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="modal fade" id="signupModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="signupModelLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Sign Up</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

YMMV, but the only way I was able to get this to work was putting the id into the modal class attribute.   (it was ignoring the id attribute for some reason)

So instead of 
`<div class="modal fade" id="sampleDataModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sampleDataModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`
I had to use:
`<div class="modal fade sampleDataModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sampleDataModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">`

```
<! Modal Pair>
<dl class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target=".sampleDataModal">
            View Some Stuff
        </button>
        <div class="modal fade sampleDataModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="sampleDataModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl modal-dialog-scrollable">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="sampleDataModalLabel">Sample Stuff</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        some stuff
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-block" data-toggle="modal"
            data-target=".otherModal">
            View Other Stuff
        </button>
        <div class="modal fade otherModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="otherModalLabel"
            aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="otherModalLabel">Other Modal
                        </h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        other stuff
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</dl>
```